# Hard time in understanding OR Research or Paper

Tags: optimization, modeling, combinatorial-optimization, literature-research

I'm from soft-engineering background and really having a hard time when reading and understanding the formulation from a research or published paper. For example, when looking at a container loading problem or vehicle routing problem, what does that weird symbol mean, what does that notation or that positivity, negativity really mean. I know basic calculus, but more like forgot lots of them. What is a good resources or learning material to get more understanding on this issue?

Comment: There is comparedly less material on OR than other ML topics. Therefore entry barrier might seem high. I always thought Winston's Operations Research book is a wonder in this aspect.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you consider to be a "weird symbol"?

Comment: Closing the question due to lack of supporting details.