# Interpret the formulation from paper

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, gurobi, literature-research

So, based on the [last question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/hard-time-in-understanding-or-research-or-paper) about having hard time in understanding paper. I want to use this formulation in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-005-0652-x) but I don't quite understand about it. I want to use the VRPTW formulation from chapter 5. Can someone help me read maybe one or two so I can get a little bit of understanding about hows it going.

Answer (score 1):

The paper you have found is a rather technical one. The focus is on the relation between different formulations, and consequently not much space is dedicated to explaining the elements of the formulations.

As I remember the paper (it's behind pay wall, and I am on my phone, so no access for me) the authors do not provide *new* formulations. So maybe you can find papers among the references in Section 5 that go more into detail regarding the modeling. That is usually how it's done: if someone uses something in their paper without explaining much detail, you go one level up in the reference hierarchy to find the details.

Comment: Sadly the reference paper is using the same language